# How does the crew address the captain in "Das Boot"?

Tags: translation, single-word-request, sailor-jargon

In the movie [Das Boot](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082096/), the crew address the captain with a word I don't understand.

I think it may be "Kaleun", which I assume is short for "Kapitan Leutnant".

Am I right?  Is that a real word?

Comment: I remember Kaleun clearly from the director's cut version of the movie

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"[Kaleun](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kapit%C3%A4nleutnant)" is a real abbreviation, I'm not sure if this makes it a real word ;)

And yes, it means "Kapitänleutnant".

Answer (score 4):

In the current day Bundeswehr, the shortened word is "Kaleu".
The term "Kaleun" was previously used in the Wehrmacht.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kapit%C3%A4nleutnant

wherein it says:

> The official manner, in line to ZDv 10/8, of formal addressing of
>   military people with the rank Kapitänleutnant (OF-2) is “Herr/Frau
>   Kapitänleutnant“. However, as to German traditions and in line to
>   seamen´s language the abbreviation of the title to "Herr/Frau Kaleu"
>   (contemporary usage) is used in verbal communication. The commander
>   (line officer) of the Type VIIC U-boat U96 in the film Das Boot was of
>   this rank, and called "Herr Kaleun" (historical usage) by his crew.