# How does the crew address the chief in the movie Das Boot?

Tags: single-word-request, sailor-jargon

So we have seen how the crew addresses the Captain [in this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4021/how-does-the-crew-address-the-captain-in-das-boot); but how about the Chief?  At about 3:03:00, Lt. Werner asks the Chief,

> Kommen wir je wieder hoch, LI?

and calls him something like »LI«. What is he saying?

Also, the Kaleun said at about 3:07:30:

> Gut, LI

[edited to show what surely must be the answer from @Ansgar below and from listening again closely.]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about the German language.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a very specific dialogue, or a single word from a movie. As such it is unlikely to help future visitors and may possibly lead to an overlong debate as to which word was actually meant.

Comment: `Translations requests from German should be restricted to cases where a profound knowledge of German is needed for understanding a phrase or an idiom.`  @Takkat and @Carsten, marine or nautical terms can only be clarified by someone familiar with this.  As this is a seemingly small percentage of the population, I suggest this is a valid question.

Comment: @Takkat: Since it’s from a well-known movie, this can be actually interesting for future visitors and I would consider this to be of general interest. But maybe, we should discuss this on Meta.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/650/are-question-on-the-meaning-of-spoken-dialogues-from-movies-on-topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly, it is *LI* (Leitender Ingenieur)

Answer (score 2):

**Quote:** Also, the Kaleun said at about 3:07:30

> 1031
>   03:07:29,786 --> 03:07:33,582
>   Gut, **Maat**.

I used your give timestamps on three different subtitles files all in all, and the answer i found is **Maat.** Nothing to be found about `Eli or LI` so far.

<sub>**Source**: [Boot, Das (1981) - Deutsche Untertitel](http://www.podnapisi.net/boot-das-1981-untertitel-p1243026)</sub>

---

> Maat, der; -[e]s, -e[n] [aus dem Niederdeutschen > mat(e) = Kamerad]:
>   **Dienstgrad:** Matrose. Schiffsunteroffizier in der [Bundes]Marine.
>
> - (Seemannssprache, früher) Gehilfe des Steuermanns oder des Bootsmanns auf Segelschiffen.

1. ein niedriger (Unteroffizier) Dienstgrad bei der Marine.
2. jmd., der den Dienstgrad eines Maats1 trägt.

<sub>**Sources**: Britannica Encyclopaedia 2010 **|** PONS Großwörterbuch **|** Langenscheidt Großwörterbuch</sub>